# Matrix differential operator

Tags: matrix, operators

i'm new in MATHEMATICA. I want to create an operator $D^{(f)}=\partial_x+f'-\partial^2_x$ and $D^{(g)}=\partial_x+g'-\partial^2_x$ and put it into a matrix element, then multiplied by a vector whose components are functions on $x$, say $u(x), v(x)$. For example $$\begin{pmatrix}D^{(f)} & D^{(g)}\\ D^{(g)} & D^{(f)}  \end{pmatrix} \begin{pmatrix} u(x) \\ v(x) \end{pmatrix}$$

I saw the posts: [Computing with matrix differential operators](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/69149/computing-with-matrix-differential-operators), [How to do matrix operation if the first matrix is an operator?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/120324/how-to-do-matrix-operation-if-the-first-matrix-is-an-operator); but i'm very newbie on this.

My problem lives on the fact that I have problems with the matrices products because I have operators

Thanks!

EDIT: $f=f(x,y,z)$ and $g=g(x,y,z)$, both of them are function of a vector $(x,y,z)$, but we can neglect the components $y,z$ and consider only the $x$ part

Comment: Here, `f` and `g` are some functions on `x` or not? What are they?

Comment: If you write `df = (D[#, {x, 1}] + (-D[#, {x, 2}]) &);`, `dg = (D[#, {x, 1}] + (-D[#, {x, 2}]) &);`, `mat = {{df, dg}, {dg, df}} `, `vec = {u[x], v[x]}`, then `CenterDot[mat, vec]` works, with `CenterDot` given in the former of the linked questions. This is without `f` and `g` but adding them should be very straightforward.

Comment: For v11.3, `Construct` can be used, e.g.,  `Inner[Construct, {{a # &, \!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]#\) &}, {\!\(
\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(y\)]#\) &, d # &}}, {u[x, y], 
  v[x, y]}]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can start by defining our two differential operators and putting them into a matrix, like this:

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]

df[w_] := D[w, x] + f'[x] w - D[w, x, x]
dg[w_] := D[w, x] + g'[x] w - D[w, x, x]
m = {{df, dg}, {dg, df}};
```

Now we need a way for the matrix operator to act on the vector.  This is not plain multiplication.  One way to get the matrix operator to act on a vector is to define a function to do it, like this:

```
operate[matrix_, column_] := 
 Table[Inner[#1[#2] &, μ, column, Plus], {μ, matrix}]
```

The above function is basically what those other posts were saying.
Now we can use the function to apply the matrix operator to our vector.

```
result = operate[m, {u[x], v[x]}];
result // MatrixForm

(*
  {u[x] f'[x] + v[x] g'[x] + u'[x] + v'[x] - u''[x] - v''[x], 
   v[x] f'[x] + u[x] g'[x] + u'[x] + v'[x] - u''[x] - v''[x]}  *)
```

We could have defined our functions `f[x]` and `g[x]` at any point.  For example, we can do it now, as

```
f[x] := Sin[x]
result
(*
  {Cos[x] u[x] + v[x] g'[x] + u'[x] + v'[x] - u''[x] - v''[x], 
   Cos[x] v[x] + u[x] g'[x] + u'[x] + v'[x] - u''[x] - v''[x]}
*)
```

Comment: Simpler is `operate[matrix_, column_] := Inner[Compose, matrix, column]` although `Compose` is no longer documented.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of my [`DifferentialOperator`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/162590/45431) paclet to do this. Install with:

```
PacletInstall["https://github.com/carlwoll/DifferentialOperator/releases/download/0.1/DifferentialOperator-0.0.2.paclet"]
```

and load with:

```
<<DifferentialOperator`
```

Here is an animation:

[image]

Also, notice how I used two different variations of the second order differential operator.

Here is the final answer so that it can be compared with other answers:

```
{
u[x] f'[x] + v[x] g'[x] + u'[x] + v'[x] - u''[x] - v''[x], 
v[x] f'[x] + u[x] g'[x] + u'[x] + v'[x] - u''[x] - v''[x]
}
```